# how can I print multiple rows data in one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot-table

I having two table with mysql as below?

```
TimeSchedule 

subID | date  | venue  | timeslot 

1     |  8-12 |  ABC   |   10 - 12

2     |  8-12 |  ABC   |   2 - 4 

subject

subID | name 

1     | Games
2     | Music
```

I want to display these two table data as following?

```
Date | 10 - 12 | 2 - 4 |Venue

8-12 | Game    | Music | ABC
```

Comment: This confuses me slightly, but perhaps @Saharsh poorly edited your question. Please edit your question to make your table layout clearer.

Comment: The thing you want to do is called "pivoting" your result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.date, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.timeslot = '10 - 12' THEN s.name ELSE '' END) AS `10 - 12`,  
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.timeslot = '2 - 4' THEN s.name ELSE '' END) AS `2 - 4`,  
       t.venue  
FROM TimeSchedule t
INNER JOIN `subject` s ON t.subID = s.subID  
GROUP BY t.date;
```